# Como ir para um link ao clicar em uma div sem usar <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso redirecionar a página para um *link* específico ao clicar em uma `div`, sem usar o `<a href>` do HTML.

Estou usando HTML, CSS e jQuery e PHP.

Segue um trecho do código:

```
<div id="btn-oculto2" style="display:none;">
    <div id="btn-oculto" >Novo acesso</div>
    <div id="btn-oculto" >Liberar conte&uacutedo</div>
</div>
```

Eu preciso que o Novo acesso redirecione a pagina sem `<a href"">Novo Acesso</a>`,apenas clicando em cima da `div "btn-oculto"`

Comment: Existe algum motivo para não usar o `a href`?

Comment: Atá onde eu sei, qualquer elemento pode ter um Evento onClick atrelado à ele. Nesse caso, basta ter, por exemplo, um *hasmap* com classes ou ID como chave e os URLs como valor. Quando o elemento for clicado, você busca a chave corresponde e, se existir, redireciona. Mas eu reforço veementemente o comentário do @bigown. *KISS* (*Keep it simple, stupid!*) se você impor que essa funcionalidade funcionará estritamente com Javascript, estará obstruindo seu código desnecessáriamente.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 12):

Em HTML5 dá para fazer isto:

```css
#divlink {
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
a.link {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
        <div id="divlink">
            Novo acesso
        </div>
    </a>
```

Se não quer que pareça um *link*, use CSS para colocar no estilo que desejar.

Também pode fazer isto:

```css
#divlink {
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.link {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divlink" onclick="window.location='http://example.com';">
    Novo acesso
</div>
```

Dá para fazer sem JavaScript, o que é recomendável. Note que ter um `a href` não é problema. Eu acho que seu requisito não é este.

```css
#divlink {
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
a.link {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divlink">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">Novo acesso</a>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/LinkWithoutHref.js).

Answer (score 5):

Sim, é possível, precisas de usar `window.location = "http://www.novo.url";`

Exemplo (http://jsbin.com/zotuyifare/1/):

```js
$('#btn-oculto').click(function(){
  window.location = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/";
});
```

```css
#btn-oculto{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn-oculto2">
    <div id="btn-oculto" >Novo acesso</div>
    <div id="btn-oculto" >Liberar conte&uacutedo</div>
</div>
```

Sugiro, como juntei no exemplo, usar `cursor: pointer;` nesse pseudo-link para o usuário perceber a funcionalidade.

Sugiro também usar classes em vez de ID se tiveres mais que um caso desta funcionalidade.

Answer (score 4):

Basta pegar o evento de *click* no elemento que você gostaria que ocorresse a ação.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com'
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div>Novo Acesso</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So usar o onclick="(window.location='url'

```
<div id="btn-oculto2" style="display:none;" onclick="(window.location='url')">
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Segue um trecho do código:

```html
<div id="btn-oculto2" style="display:none;" onclick="(window.location='url')">
    <div id="btn-oculto" >Novo acesso</div>
    <div id="btn-oculto" >Liberar conte&uacutedo</div>
</div>
```